# javascript onclick function not working in django template (problem most certainly is with the js code, i have verified the correctness of django)

Tags: javascript, html, django

what i am trying to do is create a like button just like Instagram's heart. The page must not reload when the like button is clicked, it must simply fill in with the specified color. This is how i am rendering the button in my page:

```
                    <a href="#" onclick=
                        "favPost('{% url 'events:post_unfavorite' post.id %}', {{ post.id }} );return false;"
                        {% if post.id not in favorites %} style="display: none;" {% endif %}
                        id="favorite_star_{{post.id}}">
                    <span class="fa-stack" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                    <i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x" style="color: yello;"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                    <!-- the second href -->
                    <a href="#" onclick=
                         "favPost('{% url 'events:post_favorite' post.id %}', {{ post.id }} );return false;"
                        {% if post.id in favorites %} style="display: none;" {% endif %}
                        id="unfavorite_star_{{post.id}}">
                    <span class="fa-stack" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                    <i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x" style="display: none; color: yello;"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
                    </span>
                    </a>
```

here, events is the name of my django app, "post" is the relevant post on which i need to add the like and "favorites" is a list of favorite posts associated with any posts.

Though i have double checked and i am almost certain that there are no issues with my python code. But i'll still provide the functions for reference.

These are the two views i have created for adding and deleting a favorite:

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def AddFavoriteView(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("Add PK",pk)
        t = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
        t.num_likes = t.num_likes + 1
        fav = Fav(user=request.user, post=t)
        try:
            fav.save()  # In case of duplicate key
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return HttpResponse()

@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def DeleteFavoriteView(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("Delete PK",pk)
        t = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
        t.num_likes = t.num_likes - 1
        try:
            fav = Fav.objects.get(user=request.user, post=t).delete()
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return HttpResponse()
```

The problem is, nothing happens when i click the rendered star, and i get this error in my browser console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: favPost is not defined

Can someone please help me with this?
Thank You

Comment: Sounds like wherever you defined the JS method `favPost` has not been included in the rendering of the view using that method. Make sure you're including your application JS in that view

Comment: Can you show the javascript code and how/where you have included it in the html template?

Comment: @name-andy i resolved the issue